# My java web app does not deploy unless I include the jstl-1.2 jar, however when I do include that I get duplicate tld warning

Tags: maven, jar, jstl, tomcat7

Where are the duplications likely to be ?

I have the normal tomcat 7 lib folder, nothing added or taken away.

If I use (so the jar is not deployed):

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
 <version>1.2</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I get

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport
```

But when I remove scope provided and deploy the jstl jar I get warnings starting with :

```
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
```

Comment: Try to run `mvn dependency:tree` and see if you have the `jstl.jar` in several places.

Comment: When I change the one dependy in pom, it fails to deploy ... I thouhgt one of the included libs would contain the duplication

Comment: Check out this answer and see if it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8045562/1350762