# ERROR tiles.InsertTag - ServletException in '/tiles/content/Profile.jsp': javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

The JSP page worked fine but fails when I add the `<c:if>` conditional tag on it.

I have the `jstl-impl-1.2.jar` files in the WEB-INF/lib folder and the following tag library declarations in the jsp page:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>application.ApplicationResources</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

I am using tomcat 7.0 with java 6. When I created the new dynamic web project in eclipse, I set the dynamic web module version to 2.4. The page has `<c:set/>` tags, they are working fine, but when I use the `if` conditional tag I get the following error:

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 15, 2014 10:02:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.ConditionalTagSupport
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1207)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1435)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1647)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:986)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1258)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1435)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:656)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
    at org.apache.jsp.tiles.layout.nfm_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f2(nfm_jsp.java:349)
    at org.apache.jsp.tiles.layout.nfm_jsp._jspService(nfm_jsp.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:656)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.Profile_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f0(Profile_jsp.java:154)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.Profile_jsp._jspService(Profile_jsp.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(RequestProcessor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:345)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:560)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:209)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15810 [http-bio-8085-exec-5] ERROR tiles.InsertTag  - ServletException in '/tiles/content/Profile.jsp': javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:343)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:656)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
    at org.apache.jsp.tiles.layout.nfm_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f2(nfm_jsp.java:349)
```

The error what i think might be in `profile.jsp`

```
%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html-el" prefix="html-el"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="/fmt"%>


<html:html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="language" content="en-us" />

<tbody class="scrollContent">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="label"><fmt:message key="label.account.number" /></span></td>
        <td><span class="bold "><c:out value="${customerMap.CustomerID}" /></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="label"><fmt:message key="label.name.primary" /></span></td>
        <td><c:out value="${customerMap.CustName}" /></td>
    </tr>

    <c:if test="${JointName != null}">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="label"><fmt:message key="label.name.joint" /></span></td>
            <td><c:out value="${JointName}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="label"><fmt:message key="label.email" /></span></td>
        <td><c:choose>
                <c:when test="${customerMap.Email == '' || customerMap.Email == null}">
                    <html-el:link action="Email?path=profile" styleClass="DetailButton">
    Add E-Mail Address
```

Comment: Try to look at this [answer][1]. I think you have same problem


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045272/javax-servlet-servletexception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-js?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: thanks there was some changes need to be made in taglib  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  we need to add jsp in the declaration <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>....this worked for me after some research