# cannot run a jsp file, jstl

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am new to jsp and I am having this weird problem of running this `emp.jsp` file. I know it's very basic but I am stuck for two days now :P.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sql:setDataSource var="connection" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutorials" user="root" password="" />
    <sql:query var="result" dataSource="${connection }">
        select * from registration
    </sql:query>

    <table border="0" width="75%">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>password</th>
            <th>usertype</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="col" items="${result.rows }">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${col.id}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${col.name}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${col.password}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${col.usertype}"></c:out></td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and error is this

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/SQLExecutionTag
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

this is my web.xml file as asked by @rajani

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Tutorials</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045272/javax-servlet-servletexception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-js

Comment: after adding those new jars and cleaning the project now new error is showing, the tag handler class was not found for sql:query

Comment: Remove JSTL SQL Tags from JSP, they are NEVER ok to be in JSP fiile, transfer them into Sevlet, add data to request and render JSP with getRequestDispatcher() method.

Answer (score 1):

Add **jstl.jar** to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar this file is add to my web-inf/lib and working correctly

Comment: You didn't specify the password in SQL configuration, **<sql:setDataSource var="connection" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutorials" user="root" password="" />**

Comment: because there is no password in my database@ rajani

Comment: Adding **jstl-1.2.jar** should resolve the issue. Try to **clean and build** your project after adding the jar if it doesn't exist

Comment: i cleaned the project build it again but still not running even restarting eclipse isnt working

Comment: Can you display **web.xml**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76898/discussion-between-dhruv-parashar-and-deepika-rajani).

Comment: @DhruvParashar you said **javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar**  this file is included in project, is it? If yes then add **jstl-1.2.jar** too. **javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar** does not contain all the required classes

Comment: Download it from here http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar and try to execute it again after **clean and build**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the jstl dependency on your class path:

If you are using Maven, make sure you have the dependency for jstl artifact:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: well i really dont know how to do that for now can u please tell me how to do it i am using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This exception suggests that the JSTL API is missing in the runtime classpath. You seem to have only the JSTL impl. I suggest to remove it and use jstl-1.2.jar instead which has both the API and impl bundled.

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: Are you using Maven in your project?

Comment: its inside web-inf/lib only and no i dont know how to use maven for now

Comment: Can u check once again whether you copied all required jar files or not?? Servelt-api.jar, jsp-api.jar and jstl jar files

Comment: Servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar are not inside my project though i have included mysql-connector.jar and jstl1.2.jar which i guess doesn't need Servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar

Comment: mysql-connector.jar file is required for connecting to Database from java. Remaining two jar files from server side (Servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar). Without these jar files Tomcat not able to run your web project. Please add these two jars and try it.